# Ember-Data relationship for objects that have relationships to other instances of the same object

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, ember-data

I am converting a project from Backbone (w/ Backbone Relational for ORM) to Ember and I cannot find in the documentation an example of how to use DS.belongsTo to reference an object of the same type.

In otherwords, I have the following model definition (generic pseudo-code for clarity).

```
BoxModel
  Text = String
  BoxParent = BoxModel (referenced by id)
```

I want to re-create this structure in Ember for client-side manipulation etc.

I am also using requirejs so all my object targets for DS.belongsTo have to be included in the define statement and made available as parameters to the anonymous function.

As such, I doubt I can use something like this:

```
define ([ 'textbox'  ]), function(TextBox) {
  return DS.Model.extend({
    BoxParent: DS.belongsTo(TextBox)
   });
});
```

The reference to the current class definition is not likely to work.  In Django, this type of relationship is handled with the special target of "self" but I cannot find any equivalent solution in Ember.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

As a final note, this relationship can also be null because not all TextBoxes must have a parent (this is inevitable with this type of relationship unless you have infinite circular references.

Thanks!
Steve

Comment: hi all I wanted to drop this here as I found it extremely useful and succinct as an answer to my question.  I have not yet implemented it in my own project to verify that it works so I'll leave this un-answered for the immediate time-being in case people want to add to the discussion.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727512/self-join-with-ember-data

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your model name around quotes to use a non initialized model name.

```
App.Box = DS.Model.extend([
  parent: DS.belongsTo('App.Box')
});
```