# Ember recursive parent-child relationship errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I have a rails backend for which I'm trying to make an Ember.js admin panel. Basically there are categories that can be parents to other categories and categories can have many "stickers" but "stickers" can also have many categories. Please consider the backend structure immutable in this(I can fiddle with the serializer, but that's it). Here are my serializers:

**Category Model:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_cats, class_name: "CatToCat",foreign_key: "child_id"
  has_many :children_cats, class_name: "CatToCat",foreign_key: "parent_id"

  has_many :parents, through: :parent_cats
  has_many :children, through: :children_cats
end
```

**Category to Category Model:**

```
class CatToCat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
  belongs_to :child, class_name: "Category"
end
```

**Sticker:**

```
class StickerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  attributes :id, :text, :audio, :created_at, :image, :smallImage, :updated_at, :stickerServerID
    has_many :categories
end
```

**Category:**

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  attributes :id, :name, :catImage, :created_at, :catOrder, :catServerID, :updated_at
  has_many :stickers
  has_many :children
  has_many :parents
end
```

Here are the Ember Models:

**Sticker:**

```
App.Sticker = DS.Model.extend({
    audio: DS.attr("string"),
    image: DS.attr("string"),
    smallImage: DS.attr("string"),
    stickerServerID: DS.attr("string"),
    text: DS.attr("string"),
    updated_at: DS.attr("date"),
    created_at: DS.attr("date"),

    categories: DS.hasMany("category")
});
```

**Category:**

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    catImage: DS.attr("string"),
    catOrder: DS.attr("string"),
    catServerID: DS.attr("string"),
    updated_at: DS.attr("date"),
    created_at: DS.attr("date"),

    stickers: DS.hasMany("sticker"),

    children: DS.hasMany("category",{inverse:'parents'}),
    parents: DS.hasMany("category",{inverse:'children'})
});
```

**Store:**

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(attr){
    console.log("keyForAttribute:"+attr+"->"+this._super(attr));
  if (attr == "smallImage" || attr == "stickerServerID" || attr == "catOrder" || attr == "catImage" || attr == "catServerID"){
    console.log("try:"+attr);
    return attr;
  }else{
    return this._super(attr);
  }
});

App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: '-active-model'
});
```

The error that Chrome reports:

> Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for 'child'

The error that Firefox reports is useless :-/

Happy to add any other info that is helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having this same problem setting up ancestry in ember: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474369/error-in-parent-child-relationships-in-ember I've gotten various advice, but not sure what is supposed to be best practices and haven't gotten it working properly.

Comment: Please let me know if you do find something that works^^;

Comment: The closest I've found to work is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727512/self-join-with-ember-data but my use of it only gives me correct data on page load, when I link to anything else it doesn't reload the data. I could use `reload()`, but this seems sucky.

Comment: Having the same issue, I guess the problem lies in Rails because it is rendering the children in a separate array in the JSON output, Which should just be rendered in the same array as it parents; the `categories` array.

Comment: oh and then make the connect to the parents/children on the ember side?

Comment: Yes, I got it to work now, I've added `child_ids` to the parameters in the serializer in Rails. And in Ember I've got `children: DS.hasMany('category')`. The downside is you need to always load all categories at once, because it is not loading children automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but it's not perfect.

- Add `child_ids` to the `attributes` in your serializer.
- Set `children` to a `DS.hasMany` in your model in Ember.

Rails:

```
# app/serializers/category_serializer.rb    
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, :include => true
  attributes :id, :name, :child_ids
end
```

Ember (EmberCLI):

```
// app/models/category.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  children: DS.hasMany('category'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

The problem is the serializer doesn't load the children automatically, so you need to always load all categories at once.

Comment: So this is how my children/parents are set up in the model:       has_many :parent_cats, class_name: "CatToCat",foreign_key: "child_id"
      has_many :children_cats, class_name: "CatToCat",foreign_key: "parent_id"   What should I put in the attributes?

Comment: Why are you specifying `CatToCat` as the class? Are you using HABTM relationships? If you don't, you should use `Category` as `class_name`. To answer your question, you use `:children_cats` as the relation name, so Rails creates a `:children_cat_ids` method which you should add to `attributes` in your serializer.

Comment: We are using HABTH and mapping it in rails with the above plus: has_many :parents, through: :parent_cats
      has_many :children, through: :children_cats
     But you are talking about just the ids, so it would be :children_cat_ids?

Comment: When you're using HABTM it will work, but you won't have the information of your `CatToCat` model. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Both full models added to original post!

Comment: You can use the has_many through relation if you dont need CatToCat record values. So just add child_ids to attributes in your serializer like in my answer.